# A storage mechanism has already been configured for this application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I am getting this error whenever my S#arp Architecture attempts to start and this is an problem with SQL Server (for example: SQL Server is not runing), after I start SQL Server and hit refresh, I get this error:

A storage mechanism has already been configured for this application

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to add this line before calling NHibernateSession.Init() to clear any previous initiation.

try{ NHibernateSession.Reset(); }   catch  { }

Comment: -1 for swallowing exceptions and recommending initializating multiple times.

Comment: s/initializating/initializing

Answer (score 9):

[`NHibernateSession.Init()`](http://sharp-architecture.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Data/NHibernate/NHibernateSession.cs) or `InitStorage()` is being called more than once. You're probably calling it every request, it's supposed to be called only once at startup.

Answer (score 0):

In an old application I have to maintain, this happened when the application start had issues.  So I just had to recycle the application pool in IIS.